# When was the material Unobtainium first used in movies?

Tags: first-appearance

Which was the first movie that used the word "Unobtainium" to identify an element?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5517

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has already been asked on this [site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5517), and it also mentioned on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtainium#Science_fiction)

> Unobtainium can refer to any substance needed to build some device critical to the plot of a science fiction story, but which does not exist in the universe as we know it. A hull material that gets stronger with pressure in the film [**The Core**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Core) (2003) was nicknamed unobtainium, but the concept under different names can be seen in the anti-gravity material cavorite from H. G. Wells' 1901 novel The First Men in the Moon, as well as the super-strong material scrith from Larry Niven's novel Ringworld, which requires a tensile strength on the order of the forces binding an atomic nucleus.
>
> The term was used in James Cameron's 2009 movie [Avatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar_(2009_film)), as a substance that was named (in the film's dialog) unobtanium (note the slightly different spelling). In the film, it was mined on the fictional moon Pandora, and was a room-temperature superconductor.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's not a film original. So I have seen the first film that used it and I did see it in the year 2003.

Comment: >>unobtainium, but the concept under different names can be seen in the anti-gravity material cavorite from H. G. Wells' 1901 novel The First Men in the Moon<< I think that the term "Unobtanium" implies that the substance is 1) naturally occurring; 2) rare or otherwise difficult to procure; and 3) extremely useful (because it possesses some weird physical properties). By that definition, cavorite would NOT be an example of "Unobtanium." Cavorite was a synthetic substance easily made using Helium - albeit it *did* exhibit exotic properties.